# Knockoutjs simple cascading selects

Tags: knockout.js, cascadingdropdown

I'm trying to do a simple cascading combobox using knockoutjs. My first combobox binds to 2 properties in the viewmodel:

**BusinessLines** as the source for comboboxoptions

**SelectedBusinessLine** as the selected item in the first combobox.

Each BusinessLine has a collection of Clusters.

The second combox should data bind to the SelectedBusinessLine.Clusters observable for combobox options source, and SelectedCluster for the selected option.

The problems is that the second combobox doesn't get populated at all.

Source in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2qMg/2/) (In JsFiddle the first binding doesn't work either, sry firs time use)

JavaScript

```
 var mainViewModel = null;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var mainViewModelData = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewRequestViewModel) %>;

        mainViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(mainViewModelData);

        ko.applyBindings(mainViewModel);

    });
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Business Line
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: BusinessLines,
                                   optionsText: 'Title',
                                   value: SelectedBusinessLine,
                                   optionsCaption: 'Select Business Line..'">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Cluster
            </td>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: SelectedBusinessLine.Clusters,
                                   optionsText: 'Title',
                                   value: SelectedCluster,
                                   optionsCaption: 'Select Cluster..'">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr> 
    </table>
</div>
```

**Update**:

Second **solution** (without computed props)

```
<select data-bind="options: SelectedBusinessLine() ? SelectedBusinessLine().Clusters() : [],
                                   optionsText: 'Title',
                                   value: SelectedCluster,
                                   optionsCaption: 'Select Cluster..'">
                </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version:

http://jsfiddle.net/x2qMg/4/

Your fiddle wasn't working (at all) because you did not include the Knockout Mapping JS reference (the mapping plugin in not part of the main Knockout JS) - see the Manage Resources area in the left side bar.

You'll see the biggest change I made was to use a `with` binding to only render Clusters when a Business Line has been selected.  Also note that I had to use $root.SelectedCluster as otherwise it would not be found within the Selected Business Line context created by the `with`.

Comment: Thank you very much. And if i want to have the clusters combobox always visible but with no elements if nothings is selected the the BuisnessLines comboxbox(first) what should i change?

Comment: In that case you will have to use a computed observable.  The computed property has a dependency on SelectedBusinessLine so whenever that property changes Knockout will recalculate the available Clusters. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/x2qMg/6/

Comment: Nice, thank you. I think it would have been cleaner if your could have set a direct binding to "SelectedBusinessLine.Clusters so when SelectedBusinessLine would change kncokout would also realod clusters.. i guess i'm more used to WPF binding system

Comment: If you don't have a Business Line selected then SelectedBusinessLine.Clusters does not exist.  You would get JavaScript errors.  That's why my first example did what it did, using the `with` binding so that the secondary select would only be rendered when SelectedBusinessLine was set.  By using the computed property I get around that by returning an empty array if SelectedBusinessLine is not set.

Comment: Ok, but when there are js errors with the binding, the binding should fail silently, the moment when a business line is selected the binding should reevaluate and succeed. I'm curious if i can implement this with a custom binding, something from both like "with" but no hiding..